# Python 2.8 custom texture painting active tool

Tags: python, texturing, 3d-view, add-on, texture-painting

I'm working on a addon that has a custom active tool in the viewport. This tool is supposed to allow you to do basic texture painting, while at the same time doing some other stuff.

My problem is, that I'm not aware of a way to make the active tool able to do texture painting. I know that there is some python api for texture painting, but that seems to only work in Texture Paint mode, which I don't want to access because my active tool is in object mode.

**So here's the question:**
How do I get my custom active tool to allow the user to do texture painting on a selected texture?

Comment: With this tool, are you going to then combine modes and allow the user to tweak the settings of the texture paint tool that is active?

Comment: Yes, that's the plan. It doesn't really matter to me which mode is active, as that wont change when working with the addon. The main point is that you can do texture painting and tweak the corresponding options, while having the custom active tool selected.